# creating a configuration page and passing variables to a simply.js app

Tags: javascript, arrays, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble

i developed a simply.js app that fetches bus arrival time from a webservice, problem is that as of now it work only for one stop.

i want to create a configuration page with a multiselect where i could choose multiple stops , sending them to the pebble as an array and at the press of up/down buttons i want to cycle the array to show different bus stops.
Im not good in C, i prefere javascript thats because i used simply.js.

id like to know and learn how to do it, because i think online there isnt much documentation and examples.

Answer (score 1):

Found a similar question/ issue at simply.js github page https://github.com/Meiguro/simplyjs/issues/11. The code example below comes from Meiguros first answer. The code sends the user to your configuration website, which you should configure to send json back.

You can probably copy the code example for enabling the configuration window and paste it in the begining of your main pebble app.js file. Do not forget to add  `"capabilities": [ "configurable" ],` in your appinfo.json file. If you are using cloudpebble you should go to the settings page of your app and make sure the configurable box is checked.

```
 var initialized = false;
    Pebble.addEventListener("ready", function() {
    console.log("ready called!");
    initialized = true;
    });
    Pebble.addEventListener("showConfiguration", function() {
    console.log("showing configuration");
        //change this url to yours
        Pebble.openURL('http://assets.getpebble.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/pebble-js/configurable.html');
        });
        Pebble.addEventListener("webviewclosed", function(e) {
        console.log("configuration closed");
        // webview closed
        var options = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(e.response));
        console.log("Options = " + JSON.stringify(options));
        });
```

(https:// github.com/pebble-hacks/js-configure-demo/blob/master/src/js/pebble-js-app.js - remove space after https://)

To then push the settings back to the pebble i think you need to add

```
Pebble.sendAppMessage(options);
```

just before

```
    console.log("configuration closed");
    // webview closed
```

I found this out at the last post on this pebble forum thread http://forums.getpebble.com/discussion/12854/appmessage-inbox-handlers-not-getting-triggered-by-javascript-configuration-data

You can aslo find a configuration website example named configurable.html in the same git as the code example at https:// github.com/pebble-hacks/js-configure-demo remove space after https://

Hope this helps a bit on the way to achieving your goal

Answer (score 1):

So the configuration page is a web page, and you can host it and provide your URL as mentioned by Ankan above.

Like this:

```
 Pebble.openURL('http://assets.getpebble.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/pebble-js/configurable.html');
```

Lets say you decide to take the name and age of the user in the configuration page, you would have two text fields for them to enter their information, then you would have a submit button. For the submit button write a javascript function which uses jQuery to take the values of the text fields onclick, then save those values to a variable, and use JSON to send them to the phone. Here is an example of a **fully created configuration web page**: [https://github.com/pebble-hacks/js-configure-de](https://github.com/pebble-hacks/js-configure-demo/blob/master/configurable.html)mo

Enjoy.